# Finding the minimum weight circuit that passes through vertices u and v

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have an undirected and connected (not complete) graph of vertices, where ***u*** and ***v*** can be any 2 distinct vertices. I want to construct the minimum weight circuit that starts from a vertex ***u***, passes through ***v***, then returns back to ***u*** without repeating any edges. Can this be done by doing the following?

1. Finding the shortest path from ***u*** to ***v*** - call this **p1**
2. Removing all constituent edges of **p1** from the graph
3. Finding the new shortest path from ***v*** to ***u*** - call this **p2**
4. Returning all deleted edges to the graph, and concatenating **p1** and **p2** together - call this **c1**

Is **c1** the minimum weight circuit that can be constructed, considering the constraint of passing through both ***u*** and ***v***? If so, how can I prove it, if not, why not?

It seems to make sense to me, as all the paths contained within **c1** are also shortest paths themselves, however I can't quite shake the feeling that I might be missing something.

EDIT: I have changed "fully connected graph" to "connected graph". "fully" implied that the graph is complete, which is not what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is equivalent to finding two edge-disjoint paths from *u* to *v* while minimizing their total weight. This is a special case of [Minimum Cost Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) with a flow of two, so it can be solved in polynomial time and is likely not NP-hard. [Suurballe's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suurballe%27s_algorithm) solves it for directed graphs, and it should be possible to adapt it to undirected graphs (it seems that [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_disjoint_shortest_pair_algorithm) is attempting to do this).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a counterexample:

[image]

In a case of complete graph, assume all edges not shown in the picture to have some large weight (like 1000).

The `p1` would find the shortest path `1 - 1 - 1` and exclude it, prohibiting the actual answer of `3 - 1` + `1 - 3`.

---

As suggested by [Falk Hüffner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69866062/1349366), this task can be solved by [Edge disjoint shortest pair algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_disjoint_shortest_pair_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wrongly implied that the graph was complete, but I see your counterexample covers both cases.

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is no clever solution, short of examining all paths, that covers all cases. But if we suppose that removing `p1` does not make `u` unreachable from `v`, does my algorithm solve the task?

Comment: @HervéSV, of course not. Add an edge from `u` to `v` with weight of 1000 in my example.

Comment: right, I see. Thank you for your clear example and explanation

Comment: @HervéSV, I was wrong regarding the class of this problem. You were on the right track with your approach. See [Falk Hüffner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69866062/1349366) answer.